# Cppcheck integration with CMake for SOME targets

Tags: cmake, cppcheck

What I couldn't figure out is that if I had a CMake project with subfolders holding their own CMakeLists.txt and their own targets:
I want to integrate Cppcheck for specific targets and not all of them.
So What would I need to include in the root CMakeLists.txt and what would change in the CMakeLists of the subfolders in this case?

Comment: There could be no generic answer to this question. Cmake does not define or encourage  any kind of specific organization of files or the way the projects interact with each other.

Comment: @user7860670 Would I need to make a custom target necessarily though just for cppcheck? The way Im doing it is appending the arguments to CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK but not really successful

Answer (score 3):

Set [`<LANG>_CPPCHECK`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LANG_CPPCHECK.html) target property for every target you want to and clear it from every target you do not want to check with cppcheck.

---

The following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.11)
project(test)
file(WRITE a.c "int main() { int a[10]; a[10] = 0; }")
file(WRITE b.c "int main() { int b[10]; b[10] = 0; }")
file(WRITE c.c "int main() { int c[10]; c[10] = 0; }")
file(WRITE a.h "static inline void f() { int a[10]; a[10] = 0; }")
file(WRITE b.h "static inline void f() { int b[10]; b[10] = 0; }")
file(WRITE c.h "static inline void f() { int c[10]; c[10] = 0; }")
add_executable(a a.c a.h)
add_executable(b b.c b.h)
add_executable(c c.c c.h)
set(cppcheck
  cppcheck
  "--enable=warning"
  "--inconclusive"
  "--force" 
  "--inline-suppr"
)
set_target_properties(a PROPERTIES C_CPPCHECK ${cppcheck})
set_target_properties(b PROPERTIES C_CPPCHECK ${cppcheck})
```

Results in that only `a.c` and `b.c` files are checked, and `c.c` file is not checked.

```
$ cmake -S. -B_build -GNinja ; cmake --build _build
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/10/_build
[3/6] Building C object CMakeFiles/b.dir/b.c.o
Checking ../b.c ...
../b.c:1:26: error: Array 'b[10]' accessed at index 10, which is out of bounds. [arrayIndexOutOfBounds]
int main() { int b[10]; b[10] = 0; }
                         ^
[4/6] Building C object CMakeFiles/a.dir/a.c.o
Checking ../a.c ...
../a.c:1:26: error: Array 'a[10]' accessed at index 10, which is out of bounds. [arrayIndexOutOfBounds]
int main() { int a[10]; a[10] = 0; }
                         ^
[6/6] Linking C executable a
```

---

> however, if I wanna execute cppcheck --project=compile_commands.json, it would still output style issues in targets I ignored.

Yes, `cppcheck` gets **all** the files from `compile_commands.json` and checks them. If you want to use `--project`, parse `compile_commands.json` with a JSON tools to filter only the files you are interested in and remove the files you are not interested in checking, and then pass the resulting file to `cppcheck`.

Comment: This make sense and I tried that; however, if I wanna execute `cppcheck --project=compile_commands.json`, it would still output style issues in targets I ignored.. So I'm not sure what's overriding this

Comment: `what's overriding this` If you specify `--project` option with `cppcheck` then it will use the files specified in project file.

Comment: Okay I understand.. so I guess my only option is to ignore files with `-i` while executing this command.. OR maybe I could create a custom target which can execute post-build but still only check the targets I want without having to manually ignore files like the former (if you see it as feasible)...
PS: My insistence on also running cppcheck after building is for CI purposes

Comment: I do not understand. Do not specify `--project=compile_commands.json`. | Anyway, while there is some cppcheck integration with cmake, it's sometimes "not enough". If it is, indeed write a separate work pipeline for cppcheck (and other static checkers). `I want without having to manually ignore files like the former` You can let cmake store list of files in a target, and then use that to generate arguments for cppcheck. Indeed possibly as a separate cmake custom target.